# How do I stop an AppleScript script that is stuck in an endless loop without restarting my Mac?

Tags: macos, applescript, script

I stupidly ran an AppleScript script on my Mac running macOS Mojave and the script is running in an endless loop. I thought something obvious like pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key would end the program. However, neither the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key or anything like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> etc works.

How can I interrupt the loop and end the script using a hotkey or similar method?

**I tried to click the program but it won't let me unless the loop of the keystrokes stop.**

**NOTE:** I need to save my work so I can't shut it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.apple.com/en-il/guide/script-editor/scrptedshtcut/mac

The answer is indicated here. Command + period (.)

Comment: Please write the answer here not just a link

Comment: You can also kill (force quit) _Script Editor_ and, provided it autosaves your documents, the scripts will be restored to the last compiled versions when you reopen.  This is sometimes useful when the keyboard shortcut isn’t viable which is the case in a few possible situations that aren’t uncommon.